Cant load user with LdapUserProvider : Could not complete search with dn
With LdapUserProvider i have some errors when i try to load my user.
In this method :
    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
{
    try {
        $this->ldap->bind($this->searchDn, $this->searchPassword);
    } catch (InvalidCredentialsException) {
        throw new InvalidSearchCredentialsException();
    }

    $identifier = $this->ldap->escape($identifier, '', LdapInterface::ESCAPE_FILTER);
    $query = str_replace('{username}', '{user_identifier}', $this->defaultSearch, $replaceCount);

    if ($replaceCount > 0) {
        trigger_deprecation('symfony/ldap', '6.2', 'Using "{username}" parameter in LDAP configuration is deprecated, consider using "{user_identifier}" instead.');
    }
    $query = str_replace('{user_identifier}', $identifier, $query);
    $search = $this->ldap->query($this->baseDn, $query, ['filter' => 0 == \count($this->extraFields) ? '*' : $this->extraFields]);
    $entries = $search->execute();
    $count = \count($entries);

    if (!$count) {
        $e = new UserNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $identifier));
        $e->setUserIdentifier($identifier);

        throw $e;
    }

    if ($count > 1) {
        $e = new UserNotFoundException('More than one user found.');
        $e->setUserIdentifier($identifier);

        throw $e;
    }

    $entry = $entries[0];
    try {
        if (null !== $this->uidKey) {
            $identifier = $this->getAttributeValue($entry, $this->uidKey);
        }
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException) {
    }
    dd($entry);
    return $this->loadUser($identifier, $entry);
}

my dd() gave me an array with my users Ldpa's attributes like this :

LdapUserProvider.php on line 110: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Entry {#394 ▼   -dn: "CN=test test,OU=WORK,OU=USER,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM"  

-attributes: array:48 [▼
"objectClass" => array:4 [▶]
"cn" => array:1 [▶]
"sn" => array:1 [▶]
"title" => array:1 [▶]
"description" => array:1 [▶]
"givenName" => array:1 [▶]
"initials" => array:1 [▶]
"distinguishedName" => array:1 [▶]
"instanceType" => array:1 [▶]
"whenCreated" => array:1 [▶]
"whenChanged" => array:1 [▶]
"displayName" => array:1 [▶]
"uSNCreated" => array:1 [▶]
"memberOf" => array:17 [▶]

Thats fine.
But, if i comment dd(), the method give me an error :
Could not complete search with dn "dc=DOMAIN,dc=COM", query "(sAMAccountName=test)" and filters "*". LDAP error was [1] Operations error.

On this line :
        $entries = $search->execute();

Any idea is appreciated
